# <address>.map() - What does this function map() do?

Tags: solidity, addresses

In the Uniswap contract Dispatcher.sol
(https://github.com/Uniswap/universal-router/blob/main/contracts/base/Dispatcher.sol)

```
    function callAndTransfer721(bytes memory inputs, address protocol)
    internal
    returns (bool success, bytes memory output)
{
    (uint256 value, bytes memory data, address recipient, address token, uint256 id) =
        abi.decode(inputs, (uint256, bytes, address, address, uint256));
    (success, output) = protocol.call{value: value}(data);
    if (success) ERC721(token).safeTransferFrom(address(this), recipient.map(), id);
}
```

There is this function recipient.map()

What does this function map() do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` calculates the recipient address for a command and returns the resultant recipient for the command.

See:

https://github.com/Uniswap/universal-router/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Recipient.sol